# Alternative for Microsoft.VisualBasic.Information.IsNumeric in C#

Tags: c#

```
attrval[5] = WrmService.WindowsAgent.AgentVersion;
```

From above if attrval[5] is null or not getting any value or any strings other than numeric values I want to assign attrval[5] to value '0.0.0.0' otherwise I will
display the numeric value which is coming.What coding i have to implement here

as per the information while doing googling I did this

```
attrval[5] = (WrmService.WindowsAgent.AgentVersion == null || Microsoft.VisualBasic.Information.IsNumeric(WrmService.WindowsAgent.AgentVersion)) ? 
"0.0.0.0" : WrmService.WindowsAgent.AgentVersion;
```

but Microsoft.VisualBasic.Information.IsNumeric making problems. Is there any similar one in C#?

only two outputs I required one will be numeric and one will be any other, it can be string or null whatever it i have to set in to 0.0.0.0

Comment: only two outputs i required one will be numeric and one will be any other, it can be string or null whatever it i have to set in to 0.0.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
if(!int.TryParse(WrmService.WindowsAgent.AgentVersion, out attrval[5])) attrval[5] = 0;
```

In this case, if AgentVersion is numeric, it will place the parsed value into attrval[5], otherwise it will set it to 0.

**edit**

Ah I guess you are looking for:

```
attrval[5] = string.IsNullOrEmpty(WrmService.WindowsAgent.AgentVersion) ? "0.0.0.0" : WrmService.WindowsAgent.AgentVersion;
```

Comment: but its showing error Error 4 ; expected ..If i put in this way if(!int.TryParse(WrmService.WindowsAgent.AgentVersion, out attrval[5])) attrval[5] = "0.0.0.0";
  again error

Answer (score 1):

I would recomend using something like

[Int32.TryParse Method (String, Int32)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx)

See also [C# Equivalent of VB's IsNumeric()](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/csharp-isnumeric.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You could use Int32.TryParse() to check if it is an integer value.